# AssertThrows failing the test even after the right exception is thrown

Tags: java, jdbc, junit

```
@Test
void testConnectToInvalidUrl() {
    model.setCredentials("cst8288", "8288");
    assertThrows(SQLException.class,() -> model.connectTo("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/redditreader?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=falses"));
}
```

I'm trying to test this method which connects to a MySQL database in JUnit by entering a wrong url as it will throw an SQLException, which it does, but the test fails regardless. Here is the actual method:

```
public void connectTo(String url) {

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, User, Pass);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

The Exception thrown :

```
java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'useSSL' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'falses' is not in this set.
```

I know its the extra s at the end, but since its a SQLException, shouldn't assertThrows make the test pass?

Comment: What's the output from junit?

Comment: @tgdavies
it just fails the test and this is what's printed in the console

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'useSSL' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'falses' is not in this set.

Comment: You catch the exception in your `connectTo` method, so no exception is thrown out of that method, so `assertThrows` won't catch anything and thus fail the test. Remove the try-catch from your `connectTo` method, and give it a `throws SQLException` in the method signature.